# TypeError: Clipboard.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, typeerror, clipboard.js

I am testing my clipboard tooltip code, but when I run the test it gives the error

> TypeError: Clipboard.on is not a function

### Test File

```js
let clipboard_args;
class Clipboard {
    constructor(...args) {
        clipboard_args = args;
    }
}

mock_cjs("clipboard", Clipboard);

...
...
...

rm.update_elements($content);   // here the error is caused after calling this function
```

### Main file

```js
export const update_elements = ($content) => {

   ...
   ...
   ...

   clipboard.on('success', function(e) {                    //There error will not occur without this line
         show_copied_confirmation($copy_button[0]);
    });
};
```

The mocks seems support the bare minimum functionality needed to run the existing tests with the existing code. The code seems to be fine, but I am not sure what to do in order to fix the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the dummy `on` function does the trick.

```
let clipboard_args;
class Clipboard {
    constructor(...args) {
        clipboard_args = args;
    }
    on(success, show_copied_confirmation) {
       show_copied_confirmation();
    }
}
```